# make: *** [Makefile.install_ucb:13: install-dat] Error 1

Tags: command-line, compiling

So basically i am trying to install an older program on a newer kubuntu version 20.10, it was a bit tricky because i needed some old libreries that were no longer part of the stable distribution, i managed to build back the dependencies and the make all command in prompt worked good, but when i type make install i get this error and i am really clueless at this point:

```
$ make install
mkdir -p /home/teo/rw05/bin
mkdir -p /home/teo/rw05/font
mkdir -p /home/teo/rw05/icc
mkdir -p /home/teo/rw05/demo
mkdir -p /home/teo/rw05/doc
/usr/bin/install  ./.radwarerc /home/teo/rw05/.radwarerc
/usr/bin/install  ./.radware.bashrc /home/teo/rw05/.radware.bashrc
/usr/bin/install  ../font/font.dat /home/teo/rw05/font/font.dat
/usr/bin/install: '../font/font.dat' and '/home/teo/rw05/font/font.dat' are the same file
make: *** [Makefile.install_ucb:13: install-dat] Error 1
```

Maybe i need to modify something in the makefile or install another thing ? Any help is appreciated !

Comment: What were the steps **before** `make install`? Did you configure the build with an install prefix (like `./configure --prefix=$HOME/rw05`)?

Comment: I used the following commands in the command prompt from the beggining:$ cd rw05/src to get intro the source i guess; next $ cp Makefile.linux Makefile; $ make all, at this point i encountered some errors because of missing libraries, got over them with the help of multiarch-support which allowed me to install older libraries, so far so good. Now at this stage $ make install i encounter this error

Comment: According to this [README.first](https://radware.phy.ornl.gov/ftp/radware/unix/README) file, `make install` is "not necessary to run the programs", however if you choose to do it you should "check the definition of INSTALL_DIR, INSTALL and INSTALL_BIN in the Makefile" and presumably change them to somewhere appropriate.